# how to change last value (ip address) with sed

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, ip, replace

I read the current ip address with following command line. after then i need to replace the last value with 0/24
For example. The current ip ist 192.168.178.1 and i need to replace the var value in 192.168.178.0/24

Thank you for your support and best greetings!

```
 varip=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/' )
```

Comment: Maybe this is easier to parse: `hostname -i | sed 's/[^.]*$/0\/24/'`

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following sed code at the end:

```sh
sed 's:[^.]*$:0/24:'
```

It works by replacing the last occurring sub-string that doesn't contain '.', with '0/24'. Note how I use ':' as separator for the sed command `s`, so that I can use '/' un-escaped.

---

Or go with sed all the way :)

```sh
ip addr | sed -rn '/state UP/{n;n;s:^ *[^ ]* *([^ ]*).*:\1:;s:[^.]*$:0/24:p}'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**:

```
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$/\.0\/24/'
```

But you do not need `cut`, replace it with `sed`:

```
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*\//\.0\//'
```

This command return the same output.

And you do not need `tail`, replace it with `sed` too:

```
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | awk '{print $2}' | sed '$!d;s/\.[0-9]*\//\.0\//'
```

But the **shortest way** is to use `hostname` instead:

```
hostname -I | tr -d " " | sed 's/[0-9]*$/0\/24/'
```

Output will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `perl` one liner:

```
perl -MSys::Hostname -MEnv -e ' print join ".",( unpack("C4",(gethostbyname($HOSTNAME))[4]))[0..2],"0/24\n";'
```

It is predicated on the HOSTNAME environmental variable being set to the proper machine name.

Answer (score 0):

To get Your-IP-Adress/24 use the following command:

```
ip addr | grep inet | egrep /24 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using Awk:

```
ip a | awk '/state UP/{nr[NR+2]}; NR in nr {gsub(/\.([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/,".0/24"); print $2}'
```